# Laplace Transformation Proof - Show that $L\{f_a(x) \} = \hat f(s+a)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For any number $a \gt 0$, let $f_a$ be defined as follows:

$f_a(x)=\begin{cases}f(x-a)&x\geq a\\0&0\leq x<a\end{cases}$

Show that $L\{f_a(x) \} = \hat f(s+a)$

This is what I did so far

$f_a(x)=\begin{cases}f(x-a)&x\geq a\\0&0\leq x<a\end{cases}\\\qquad=f(x-a)h(x-a)$

$\mathcal L\{f_a(x) \}=\int \limits_0^\infty f_a(x) e^{-sx}\mathrm dx\\
\qquad=\int \limits_0^\infty f(x-a)h(x-a) e^{-sx}\mathrm dx\\
\qquad =0+\int \limits_a^\infty f(x-a) e^{-sx}\mathrm dx\\
\qquad =\int \limits_a^\infty f(x-a)  e^{-sx}\mathrm dx\\
\qquad\qquad\text{let } u=x-a\\
\:\\
%\qquad =f(x-a) e^{-sx}\Big|_a^\infty\\
%\qquad=\hat f(s+a)$

Then, $du =  1 dx$

We have to change the limits after we use the u-substitution. When all of the x's convert to u's the new limits are $u=0$ to $u=\infty$

$\int \limits_a^\infty f(x-a)  e^{-sx}\mathrm dx\\
=\int_0^\infty f(u)e^{-s(u+a)}\mathrm du$

Everything turns into a mess because for some reason after we do Laplace, it's confusing to show how to satisfy these conditions.

$f_a(x)=\begin{cases}f(x-a)&x\geq a\\0&0\leq x<a\end{cases}\\\qquad=f(x-a)h(x-a)$

I'm stuck in a loop.

$\mathcal L\{f_a(x) \}=\int \limits_0^\infty f_a(x) e^{-sx}\mathrm dx\\
\qquad=\int \limits_0^\infty f(x-a)h(x-a) e^{-sx}\mathrm dx\\
\qquad =0+\int \limits_a^\infty f(x-a) e^{-sx}\mathrm dx\\
\qquad =\int \limits_a^\infty f(x-a)  e^{-sx}\mathrm dx\\
\qquad\qquad\text{let } u=x-a\\
=\int\limits _0^\infty f(u)e^{-s(u+a)}\mathrm du\:\\
=e^{-sa}\int\limits_0^\infty f(u)e^{-su}\mathrm du\\
=e^{-sa}\mathcal L\{f(u)\}\\=e^{-st}\hat f(s)$

How can I show that $L\{f_a(x) \} = \hat f(s+a)$ without using the Laplace table?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is incorrect. It should be that $({\cal L} f_\alpha)(s) =e^{-sa}({\cal L} f)(s)$.

You finished right before you wrote "Everything ....".

There you showed that $({\cal L} f_\alpha)(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-s(t+a) } dt$, which is almost finished.

Continuing, $\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-s(t+a) } dt = e^{-sa} \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st } dt = e^{-sa}({\cal L} f)(s)$, which is what I am guessing you were supposed to prove.

Comment: Can I use integration by parts?

Comment: You can, but why would you want to or need to here? There is nothing more to solve?

Comment: Do I just take another simple Laplace transform for $\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-s(t+a) } dt = e^{-sa} \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st } dt = e^{-sa}({\cal L} f)(s)$

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. The Laplace transform of $f$ is $({\cal L} f)$, which is given by the formula $({\cal L} f)(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st } dt$. The above shows that $({\cal L} f_\alpha)(s) =e^{-sa}({\cal L} f)(s)$.

Comment: oh! I was supposed to prove that $\cal L( f(s)) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t) dt  \\
  \cal L( f(s+a))=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(s+a)t} f(t) dt$
are equal to each other

Comment: You need to be careful with notation. ${\cal L} f$ is a function which is the Laplace transform of the function $f$. $({\cal L}f)(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $f$ evaluated at $s$. The notation ${\cal L}(f(s))$ is somewhat meaningless in context. People (instructors too) are very sloppy with this notation, and it leads to confusion. You were trying to show (or should have been) that $({\cal L} f_\alpha) (s) = e^{-s\alpha} ({\cal L}f )(s)$. And that is what you proved above. That is why I am confused.

Comment: What is the next part to this? I'm confused as well. Is there a Laplace transform of $f$ evaluated at $f_a$?

Comment: I don't know what to say. The statement in the title is not correct, but you have proved a correct statement. There's nothing more to be done with it. What is $F_a$?

Comment: Actually, that statement in the title is a part of my homework assignment, and I am attempting to do a complete proof on it. So, it's the book, not me. I did type it correctly on LaTex. Strange 1960s notation...

Comment: I know, I think the sloppy notation caused me endless confusion.

Comment: sorry about that, and the book doesn't help either. It explained Laplace backwards T_T

Comment: In any case, the statement in the title is incorrect. Time shifts correspond to multiplication by $s \mapsto e^{-as}$ in the frequency domain (and the other way around as well).

Comment: The problem ([page 139 here](http://scholarspace.manoa.hawaii.edu/handle/10125/21735)) appears to be a bastard hybrid of two true facts: if $F(s)={\cal L}\{f\}(s)$ then (a) the Laplace transform of $f(t-a)h(t-a)$ is $e^{-as}F(s)$ and (b) the Laplace transform of $e^{-at}f(t)$ is $F(s+a)$.

Comment: @anon: Wow, how did you find that? Problem 9 (p. 131) is definitely wrong.

Comment: OP [came to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12316622#12316622). :-)

Comment: @anon: I pointed out the incorrect statement at least three times :-(

Comment: Oh man! And this is part of my homework assignment. Thanks for pointing this out guys.